# Cycle2 hide slides before load

Tags: loading, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I've seen some attempts at solutions to this problem, but I can't get them to work.

I'm using cycle2 like this:

```
<div id="slideShow" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div.slides" data-cycle-prev="#slideShowPrev" data-cycle-next="#slideShowNext">
```

It works well, but on loading it shows all the slides below each other.

I've tried the solution suggested on cycle2 website:

```
#slideshow img, #slideshow div { display: none }
#slideshow img.first { display: block }
```

But, sadly, this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
.slides {display: none;}
.slides.cycle-slide {display: block;}
```

This hides your slides until the plugin is loaded and starts doing the magic.
In your CSS, you're adding a display block to an image child of a hidden div; if you want to show the 1st slide too, until plugin's sentinel kicks in, you can do this:

```
.slides {display: none;}
.slides:first-child, .slides.cycle-slide {display: block;}
```